# Rails 6 - Can't seem to load images from my css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have this project where I want to use a certain background image I have in app/javascript/images (all my images are there). When I use them in my html with the <%= image_pack_tag ... %> it works perfectly. But somehow when I try this:

```
header.masthead {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  padding-bottom: calc(10rem - 4.5rem);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8) 0%, rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8) 100%), image-url('images/singapore.jpg');
}
```

It doesn't load at all... When I inspect the code, it says module not found. I suspect it's because webpack doesn't compile the images from CSS although it does from my html code when I use image_pack_tags.

Javascript Directory:

```
├── stylesheets
│   ├── application.scss
│   └── style.scss
├── packs
│   ├── application.js
│   └── script.js
└──  images
    └── singapore.jpg
    └── ...
```

application.js :

```
const images = require.context('../images', true);
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true);
```

Comment: This may not be exactly what you want but you can set the background image of the element using js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039290/how-to-set-rails-background-image-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

So basically, I switch my images to the asset pipeline and used this:

```
asset-url('photo.jpg')
```

that's all it took.